# Reading and writing files in iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file

I'm new to writing iPhone applications. I'm writing an application to read and write all kinds of text and image files. I have read that an iPhone application can only read and write read from files in their sandboxed tmp and documents folders.

Is there a common folder in iPhone to place files so that they can be read by any other application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such "common folder". However, from [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html):

*To share files between applications, use a document interaction controller object.*

Not sure if that's what you want, but it seems like the closest you can get. More info [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: thanks andre, it gives me the idea on overall folder structure. i want to know like, for example, if place one .txt file in one folder(some common folder like photos, music, documents for all applications) it should be accessible by all application, not the sand-box one.

Comment: Well, like I said, I don't think there is such a folder. I looked it up on the first link in my post and the only mention I saw of something remotely similar to that was the one I mentioned.

Comment: There definitely is not.  That's very much against everything Apple intended for iOS.  However, if you have a jailbroken iPhone/iPad, then the world (or file system) is your oyster.